# How to sort values fed to a reducer in a specific order

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In my map-reduce job, the mapper's output type is `<Text, FileAlias>` and the class `FileAlias` has two attributes as follows

```
   public class FileAlias extends Configured implements WritableComparable<FileAlias>{

    public boolean isAlias;
    public String value;
      ...
   }
```

For each output key (of type `Text`), only one of the output values (of type `FileAlias`) has attribute `isAlias` set as true. I would like this output value to be the first item in the `OutputCollector` fed to the reducer. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [setGroupingComparatorClass](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setGroupingComparatorClass%28java.lang.Class%29) method on the `Job` object.  You should be able to implement a comparator that makes `FileAlias` with `isAlias == true` first in the Iterable that is passed to the reduce task.